# bash прочитать из строки значение

Tags: linux, bash, top

команда `top -b -n 1 -u xxx | tail -1` выдает строку с нужным значением. Это значение нужно присвоить переменной для дальнейших действий. Вопрос как это сделать?

Такое не прокатывает:

```
$строка
{
read a b c ...
} < $переменная

echo $c
```

Comment: переменная=команда_заключенная_в_обратные_апострофы

Answer (score 3):

Возможно

```
MYVAL=`top -b -n 1 -u xxx | tail -1`
```

Comment: Спасибо, решил через z=$(echo $строка | awk ' {print $9} ')

Answer (score 1):

решил через

```
z=$(echo $строка | awk ' {print $9} ')
```